# How can I test an application for thread safety?

Tags: c++, multithreading, testing, thread-safety

I have a working C++ application, using the same variables and objects in different threads without thinking about the consequences. I want to improve the application to be *thread-safe* (using `mutex`, `atomic`, etc...) - how can I test that the things I want to implement actually work?

My point is, that my application is already working fine without this - but I'm pretty sure it's just working because a possible error has not happend yet, and not because I have done something to prevent an error.

Comment: You can't test for thread safety.  Most of the unsafe operations are Undefined Behaviour and by definition (of UB) may appear to work.  You can only design for thread safety.  You can by testing prove that code is __not__ thread safe, but you can never prove by testing that the code __is__ thread safe.

Comment: upgrading to thread-safety afterwards is difficult and sometimes impossible without major redesign. You should rather design for thread-safefty from the start.

Comment: there is no simple recipe for testing either. Use thread-safe datastructures that you can unittest and build upon them.

Comment: You need to *analyzer* it for thread-safety.

Answer (score 0):

The same way that you can test for any undefined behaviour. Write comprehensive tests, run them with sanitisers, and hope for the best.

For the case of thread safety in particular, you'll want to write tests that operate on shared data in parallel and use a thread sanitiser.

Always keep in mind that no test is sufficient to prove that there is no undefined behaviour in the program.

Comment: Re, "...hope for the best." _Not_ satisfactory when "the best" can mean that after weeks or even months of testing, you find no fault, and you ship the product. Then, six months later, some customers install an OS upgrade, and some other customer moves their servers onto new hardware, and everything goes to Hell. (Don't ask me how I know!!)

Comment: @SolomonSlow Whether it is satisfactory or not, hope is all you can get. There is no way for a test to prove the lack of undefined behaviour. Better keep testing the product after shipping... if your customers are willing to pay for it.